# Fork() and for - reentering the for?

Tags: c, fork

So, i got a program that creates and matrix with random ints, and given a number it searches inside it and gives the results if its there somewhere.

i want to create forks to search in paralel inside the matrix, everyhing works, but the for that creates the forks() is repeating the results.

i've put some printfs to check what is happening and what i could see was that the parent process and the children were repeating the cycles (and thus repeating the results).

Why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> /* chamadas ao sistema: defs e decls essenciais */
#include <sys/wait.h> /* chamadas wait*() e macros relacionadas */
#include <stdlib.h> /* random */
#include <time.h> // para rand();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int num,i,j,z;
    int linhas=4, colunas=10;
    int pid[linhas];
    int matriz[linhas][colunas];

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL)); //random seed

    if (argc < 2) { printf("FNumber to search is missing use:\n ./%s number\n",argv[0]); exit(1);}
    num = atoi(argv[1]);

    //create random matrix
    for (i = 0; i<linhas; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j<colunas; j++) {
            matriz[i][j] = rand()%50+1; //matrix with randoms from 1-50
            printf("%i\t",matriz[i][j] );
        }
    }

    printf("\n\nSearch Results:\n");

    //create paralell process to search matrix
    printf("\n");
    for (i=0;i<linhas;i++) {
        pid[i] = fork();
        if (pid[i] == 0) {
            for(z=0;z<colunas;z++) {
                if (matriz[i][z] == num) { printf("Found %i at matriz[%i][%i]\n",num,i,z); }
            }
        }
        else { wait(NULL); }

    }


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `if (pid[i] == 0)` That's the child code right? What does it do after executing the code inside that block? What is the next line of code that the child will execute? Same for the parent code - what will the parent execute after the `else` block?

Comment: What mechanism did you expect would prevent the child process from iterating the `for` loop further?

Comment: Maybe i didn't express myself correctly.

@kaylum the child will execute the for loop, that what i want it to do, the parent process will wait() untill all child process finish. that is what i want.

but when i test it, it loops the for cycle more times than it should. (repeat results with the same i.

will add an result of running the program to see if it gets clearer.

Comment: @Dolda2000 didn't understand your question

Comment: Ok, after a `wait` call what will the parent do? Go back to the top of the loop....and execute `fork`.

Comment: @kaylum oh, i see now. that's way its repeating. So the wait() calls should be made outside of that for. thank you

Comment: No that alone is not going to fix it. Rather, the `fork` call needs to be protected. The usual pattern is for the child code to `return` or `exit.` That is, have a `exit(0);` call in your `if (pid[i] == 0)` block. Then you need to move the `wait` into a second loop after the current loop.

Comment: @kaylum ok, added _exit(0) inside the child.

but how will i create other loop with just wait() and the parent knows to wich child does that correspond?

of creating an equal number of waits() will make it wait for all the child created?

Comment: Do you care which child exits? No. So indeed you just need a loop that waits for the expected number of children. FYI, if you really did care about which child exited then the return value of `wait` gives you the child pid that exited.

Comment: @kaylum thank you. fixed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> /* chamadas ao sistema: defs e decls essenciais */
#include <sys/wait.h> /* chamadas wait*() e macros relacionadas */
#include <stdlib.h> /* random */
#include <time.h> // para rand();

/*Pretende-se determinar a existencia de um determinado n ́umero inteiro nas linhas de numa matriz de
numeros inteiros, em que o n ́umero de colunas e muito maior do que o numero de linhas. Implemente,
utilizando processos um programa que determine a existencia de um determinado numero, recebido como
argumento, numa matriz gerada aleatoriamente. */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int num,i,j,z;
    int linhas=4, colunas=10;
    int pid[linhas];
    int matriz[linhas][colunas];

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL)); //random seed

    if (argc < 2) { printf("FNumber to search is missing use:\n ./%s number\n",argv[0]); exit(1);}
    num = atoi(argv[1]);

    //create random matrix
    for (i = 0; i<linhas; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j<colunas; j++) {
            matriz[i][j] = rand()%10+1; //matrix with randoms from 1-50
            printf("%i\t",matriz[i][j] );
        }
    }

    printf("\n\nSearch Results:\n");

    //create paralell process to search matrix
    printf("\n");
    for (i=0;i<linhas;i++) {
        pid[i] = fork();
        if (pid[i] == 0) {
            for(z=0;z<colunas;z++) {
                if (matriz[i][z] == num) { printf("Found %i at matriz[%i][%i]\n",num,i,z); }
            }
        _exit(0);
        }       
    }

    for(i=0;i<linhas;i++) {
        wait(NULL);
    }

    return 1;

}
```